# Absurdly small icons in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, display, icons

[image]

As you can see, I can't figure out a way to enlarge only these three icons.

Besides, my login interface is also  absurdly small.

My Xubuntu version is 18.04, and the resolution is 3840*1994

I think i'm using the standard icons, because i haven't done any alteration to the icon.

Comment: Are you using standard icons?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu? What is the current resolution of your display?

Comment: My Xubuntu version is 18.04, and the resolution is 3840*1994

Comment: I think i'm using the standard icons, because i haven't done any alteration to the icon.

Comment: Try typing `xdpyinfo` at the command prompt. You should see there resolution line displaying dots per inch setting for your monitor. Typically you should have icons and cursors of many sizes installed. You do not have all sizes of these icons installed, or your resolution is to low. However, wrong resolution should also make everything else to small (text, cursors, etc.). So I guess icons of proper size cannot be found. It is also possible that app showing the icons does not use the right size.

Comment: It's 96X96 per inch, meanwhile, the DPI is 300%